# HTTP GET request doesn't work through Angular app

Tags: angular, express, mean-stack

Recently I have set up back-end for my app. I use MEAN stack and by far everything goes well. I wrote couple of HTTP handlers including POST, PATCH and GET requests. POSTs and PATCHes are working nicely, my Mongo database is taking my requests well. I can register users, log them, and update information about them.

What does not seem to work is my "get all users" requests. I tried various approaches, but none of them were successful. I guess my back-end code is ok, because when I send a GET request through the Postman app - I get the right result. But that's not working when I send the request through front-end. The main problem is that the backend function responsible for taking the JSON of users doesn't even get executed (my "console.log" added to that function does not log anything).

Here is my latest attempt:

back-end:

```
 private initializeRoutes() {
      this.router.get(`/users`, this.getAllUsers);
      this.router.patch(`/users/:id`, this.updateUserData);
  }

 private getAllUsers = async (request: express.Request, response: 
    express.Response) => {
      console.log('it works!'); // this one doesn't even show up
          this.user.find()
              .then((users) => {
                  response.send(users);
              })
              .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
```

front-end service:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import { User } from '../../_models/user';
import {environment} from '../../../environments/environment';
import {first, map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {BehaviorSubject, Observable} from "rxjs";

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class frontendService {

  private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<User>;
  public currentUser: Observable<User>;
  user;
  url = 'http://localhost:5000';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User> 
    (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')));
    this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
  }

  getAll(): Observable<User[]> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    return this.http.get<User[]>(`${this.url}/users`, {responseType: 'json', 
    headers});
  }


  register(user: User) {
    return this.http.post(`${this.url}/register`, user);
  }

  login(username: string, password: string) {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${this.url}/login`, {username, password})
      .pipe(map(user => {
        if (user) {
          localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
          this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
          this.user = user;
        }
        return user;
      }));
  }

  logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
    this.currentUserSubject.next(null);
  }

  update(user: User) {
    return this.http.patch(`${this.url}/users/${user.id}`, user);
  }
```

front-end component:

```
   getAllUsers() {
    this.frontendService.getAll().subscribe(users => {
      this.users = users;
      console.log(this.users);
    });
```

What I get is empty array, and like I said earlier, the backend function doesn't even get invoked. I tried to place the "subscribe()" function directly in the front-end service also, but that doesn't work either.

If anyone has an idea how to fix it I would be very grateful, because I know this is some minor issue, but I'm fighting it for two days right now. Almost every existing question about this topic ends on explaining the necessity of subscribing the response, but that is not the answer in my case.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console or in the build? The only thing i can think off is maybe you don't have the HttpClient imported in your main app module?

`import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';`

And add HttpClientModule into your imports array

Comment: No errors, and everything is imported correctly. Like I said, my POST and PATCH requests work nicely.

Comment: if you look at the browser network tab, do you see a call to get users? If it does, could you check the response from the network tab to see what the api is returning?

Comment: Can you add error handler inside your subscribe like this and see if there is some error logs? , (error) => {
  console.log(error);
}

Comment: I can't see a call to get users in network tab. I checked also the POST and PATCH requests there, and they show up with status 200: OK.

Comment: I added an error handler to a subscribe function and it doesn't show any errors. It just logs a empty array of users.

Comment: I also tried to set the Http headers explicitly to 'Content-Type': 'application/json', but still no effect.

Comment: if its not in the network tab, i dont think `getAllUsers()` is being called in your frontend component

Comment: it does, because it logs an empty array in the console

Comment: are you sure thats not another console log? try `console.log('front end component:', this.users);` instead. If its been called, it **HAS** to show up in the network tab

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Why does it have to show up? The backend function does not get called, therefore it doesn't show in network tab. The question is, why the backend function does not get called.

Comment: It means that  `getAll() { return this.http.get(`http://localhost:5000/users`);` this is never called. If that is called (when you subscribe), then it will have to show in the network tab that the browser has made an asynchronous request

Comment: I also console.log inside the getAll() function and it logs. I don't know what am I doing wrong in "this.http.get" request that the backend doesn't follow.

Comment: could you possibly show the code for the entire service?

Comment: I edited the original post with the service code.

Comment: does the get all request work in your postman or just to get a single result?

Comment: Can you show us a picture that with postman your get request works?

Comment: I don't really want to list my users here, but the response from Postman is just right. I get the json with all of my users, all of their properties. Also, when i type "http://localhost:5000/users" directly in my browser I still get all users.

Answer (score 0):

You need a return statement in getAllUsers server-side. And probably an await.

Comment: Adding a return statement and await also didn't change anything. Still, I can't execute the backend function from the frontend. That's why I placed my "console.log" on top of the backend function just to make sure that the function itself executes properly. But it doesn't. Through Postman it works like a charm tho. So I'm pretty sure, that the problem lies in my frontend code, but I have no idea where exactly.